# python celery: using requests package messes with my variables

Tags: python, celery

I have a celery task:

```
task.py

import requests as rq
import ...

@celery.task
def process_element(custid, element_code):
  element = Element.query.filter_by(element_code=element_code).first()
  payload = vars(element)
  del payload['_sa_instance_state']

  print('1:', payload)
  r = rq.post('http://localhost/feedbackquestion', json=payload, timeout=2)

  print('2:', payload)
  r = rq.post('http://localhost/process', json=payload, timeout=2)
```

Whats happens is that the first request takes the complete payload, while the second request only takes a fraction of the payload.
Is there any logic in this?

edit:
I have solved the issue for me by using copy.deepcopy of payload and using the copied variable in the second request. But I still do not understand whats happening here.

Comment: Are you insinuating that the two `payload` debug prints output different dictionaries?

Comment: yes, that is whats happening.